# Error: "attribute is missing the android namespace prefix",

Tags: android, xml

I have just started to learn android and the code below appears to be correct yet I'm getting the error. Please help.

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/intro"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Enter some text:"
/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you've added `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to your first XML element (after the `<xml>` tag).